# Need to create a bash script for ip filter

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have two files with multiple IP address and i want to fine those ip which in not in second file.

file one has

```
1.2.3.4
4.5.6.7
```

and file two has

```
117.239.57.130
117.239.58.226
103.248.120.245
115.249.55.100
1.2.3.4
4.5.6.7
```

so I want only

```
117.239.57.130
117.239.58.226
103.248.120.245
115.249.55.100
```

these ip which is not in file 1.

Comment: What have you tried? What were the expected and actual results, and how do these differ? What exactly is it that you want us to tell you? Super User is not a script writing service, we are a question and answers community.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty. Not usable on huge server infrastructures due to the high performance need on huge files. But for reasonable file sizes viable:

while read file2_var ; do if [ "$file2_var" != "$(grep $file2_var path/to/file1)" ]; then echo $file2_var >> file3.txt; fi ; done < path/to/file2

I am just fooling around with scripts for a month and this I did in a train, so I can't promise it works. I can't test it right now, so just test it and tell me if it works.

Had to edit it twice.. If you can read this, this should now have every paranthesis.

new edit. I messed up the grep command. corrected. Will son be able to actually test it

Last edit, I just tested it. This command works. Just pack it in a file, make it executable and start the file with #!/bin/bash and you're good. By the way, I changed the input document to path/to/file2, since I expect those document holds all IP addresses while file1 holds only the one you don't want. So, cheers. Enjoy